# What is the datatype of an Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm having trouble with Observables in terms of using it in code. If I have a method like

```
getTodos():Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Todo[]>(`${this.todosUrl}${this.todosLimit}`);
  }
```

how is this returned Observable formatted? An array?

I'm new to angular - sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this method,

```
getTodos():Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.http.get<Todo[]>(`${this.todosUrl}${this.todosLimit}`);
}
```

It returns an [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables), of `Todo` array type from the [HTTPClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) request.

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type `Observable<T>` accepts a type argument, and in this case, the array of `Todo` objects, `Todo[]`.

In short, calling the `getTodos()` method will return Observable. In order to return the values from the observable, you will need to subscribe to it.

```
getTodos().subscribe(res => {
  // console.log(res)
  // do the rest here
})
```

And after returning the observables, the returned values `res` will be of type `Todo[]`.

Answer (score 0):

From the code:

```
getTodos():Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.http.get<Todo[]>(`${this.todosUrl}${this.todosLimit}`);
}
```

1. **`getTodos()`** - is the method name.
2. **`Observable<Todo[]>`** - is the return type.
3. **`this.http.get`** - returns an Observable. But this method also accepts a **`T`** type as explained [**here in the docs**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)(Overload 8). So it then returns an **`Observable<T>`** depending the the type **`T`**. Since you're calling `get` with type **`Todo[]`**, the **`get`** method will return an **`Observable<Todo[]>`**.

Comment: How does this Observable look if I want to print it let's say?

Comment: It's a complex Object with exposed methods like `toPromise` to convert it into a Promise or `pipe` to perform operations on it. You can log it to the console and see for yourself. Here, give this a try:


```getTodos():Observable<Todo[]> {
     const obs$ = this.http.get<Todo[]>(`${this.todosUrl}${this.todosLimit}`);
     console.log(obs$);
     return obs$;
}```

Comment: So does an Observable have to take the form of an array of objects or does it not have to? The Todo data here is an array of Todo objects so do all Observables need take this form as well - array of Objects?

Comment: I'd suggest you to do your due diligence by reading the **[RxJS Docs on Observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)** once. That would most probably answer all your questions. Hope this helps.